# Pasar variable de JS a PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

Como podría pasar el valor de una variable en JS a php?
Necesito hacer un echo $localizacion; en php ya que me resulta más sencillo que hacerlo con js
He probado algo así pero no funciona

```html
$localizacion = "<script> document.write(showPosition(position)) </script>";
```

Comment: Puedes utilizar AJAX

Comment: No se muy bien como hacerlo con AJAX tampoco

Comment: Inténtalo, busca ejemplos, si ves que no sale publica lo que tengas.

Comment: Puedes pasar una variable js a php a través de ajax o a traves de un form, y de php a js con un simple echo. Te dejo un link con todos los ejemplos explicados. http://www.devservice.es/blog/como-pasar-variables-javascript-a-php/ Espero que te sirva

Comment: Hola @Tefef, [esta pregunta se ha realizado en numerosas ocasiones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=variables%20js%20php) y tiene ya respuesta en el sitio. Por favor, lee [ask] y sigue el primer consejo que encontrarás en esa página: busca e investiga.

Answer (score 1):

Sin más información sobre qué quieres hacer exactamente no lo puedo asegurar, pero en principio no se puede hacer lo que pretendes.

PHP se ejecuta del lado del servidor, y JS del lado del cliente. La secuencia sería más o menos así:

1. El cliente solicita al servidor visualizar una página .php
2. El servidor ejecuta el código PHP para generar un archivo en texto plano. Este texto plano normalmente será HTML, el cual puede contener código JS entre etiquetas "script"
3. El servidor envia el texto generado y el cliente lo recibe (el cliente normalmente será un navegador, como firefox o chrome)
4. El cliente interpretará el HTML y lo mostrará adecuadamente, ejecutando también el código javascript que contenga, pero se ejecuta EN EL CLIENTE

Como puedes ver, la ejecución del código PHP ya ha terminado por completo en el paso 2, pero la ejecución del código JS se realiza en el paso 4 y en una máquina distinta (el PHP se ha ejecutado en el servidor, el JS se ha ejecutado en el cliente).

Mediante AJAX puedes conseguir enviar información mediante JS para que sea procesada en el servidor mediante PHP, pero no creo que sea la solución que buscas. Funciona de la siguiente manera:

1. El cliente recibe el texto HTML + JS del servidor según los pasos anteriores. Muestra el contenido HTML y ejecuta el código JS.
2. En el código JS se hace una petición asíncrona al servidor usando AJAX. En esta petición se envía la localización como variable.
3. El servidor recibe la petición, la procesa y envía datos de vuelta
4. El código JS se continuá ejecutando, y puede utilizar los datos recibidos para modificar la página actual

Como ves, es posible usar datos obtenidos mediante javascript para ejecutar código PHP, pero implica un diseño más complejo. Requiere de un código JS más complejo que haga la llamada AJAX y modifique la página según los datos recibidos y requiere que el código PHP se ejecute en 2 momentos distintos.

Si das más información sobre lo que quieres conseguir podríamos sugerirte cómo hacerlo.