# como puedo mostrar una variable de javascrip y almacenarla

Tags: php, javascript

¿Cómo puedo mostrar en php las variables que me imprime el javascript?

Quiero mostrar estas variables en php:

```
var x=e.latlng.lat;
var y=e.latlng.lng;
window[e.type].innerHTML = "Lat: " + x + " Log: " +  y + " contador: "+cont ;
```

Estoy intentando así pero no me da:

```
<?php 
     $latitude ="<script>document.write(cont);</script>";
     echo "latitude =$latitude";
?>
```

Comment: Las variables del lado del cliente no puedes usarlas del lado del servidor a menos que no las mandes.  Investiga sobre Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

No puedes asignarle un valor de javascript a php de esa manera.

Cito respuesta de otro usuario

> PHP se ejecuta del lado del servidor, y JS del lado del cliente. La
>   secuencia sería más o menos así:
>
> -El cliente solicita al servidor visualizar una página .php
>
> -El servidor ejecuta el código PHP para generar un archivo en texto plano. Este texto plano normalmente será HTML, el cual puede contener
>   código JS entre etiquetas "script"
>
> -El servidor envia el texto generado y el cliente lo recibe (el cliente normalmente será un navegador, como firefox o chrome)
>
> -El cliente interpretará el HTML y lo mostrará adecuadamente, ejecutando también el código javascript que contenga, pero se ejecuta
>   EN EL CLIENTE
>
> Como puedes ver, la ejecución del código PHP ya ha terminado por
>   completo en el paso 2, pero la ejecución del código JS se realiza en
>   el paso 4 y en una máquina distinta (el PHP se ha ejecutado en el
>   servidor, el JS se ha ejecutado en el cliente).

https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/160864/23909

Lo que puedes hacer es enviar el valor de javascript mediante ajax para procesarlo en un php, y si lo que necesitas es imprimir el valor así nada más por que no, simplemente seleccionas el elemento y le agregas el valor:

```
document.getElementById("myText").value = latitude;
```